# Redirecting users to referrer page after logging in using custom login form

Tags: redirect

I am using a custom wordpress login form using the following code. I have this form in the sidebar of my site:

```
<?php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:
    $args = array(
        'redirect' => admin_url(), 
        'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
        'remember' => true
    );
    wp_login_form( $args );
} else { // If logged in:
    echo 'you are already logged in';
    wp_loginout( home_url() ); // Display "Log Out" link.
    echo " | ";
    wp_register('', ''); // Display "Site Admin" link.
}
?>
```

And in the functions.php page, I am using the following code to **redirect users to the homepage** after they log in:

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    //is there a user to check?
    if( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if( in_array( "administrator", $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    }
    else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
add_filter("login_redirect", "my_login_redirect", 10, 3);
```

**My question is:**, Is there a way to redirect users to the 'referrer page (page from where they logged in)' after they login by making changes to the above code or perhaps using a better code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who do you want to redirect? Administrators? Everybody else? Both?

Comment: @s_ha_dum both administrators and users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key part is right here-- `'redirect' => admin_url(),` in your first block of code. Whatever you set that to is where you will redirect. I don't see a reason for the second block if you are redirecting everyone.

There is no function that I can find for "this page" so you probably want `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

```
$args = array(
    'redirect' => esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 
    'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
    'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
    'remember' => true
);
wp_login_form( $args );
```

Be careful with `$_SERVER` vars: http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/php-server-vars-not-safe-in-forms-or-links/

Comment: thanks a lot, will check the code and post back here if it works for me. And will check out that link too.