# Redirect to referring page after logging in

Tags: redirect, login

I am not using any custom login plugins or any bespoke code. A few of my pages have got this bit of code in them at the very beginning.

```
<?php
    if(!is_user_logged_in())
        wp_redirect('/login/');
?>
```

So, this doesn't allow the users to view the page when not logged in. I have these pages bearing this bit of code:

```
/wp-content/my-theme/my-account/
/wp-content/my-theme/my-account/world.php
/wp-content/my-theme/my-account/subscription.php
/wp-content/my-theme/my-dashboard.php
/wp-content/my-theme/my-files.php
```

Now, when a user goes to any of the above pages, without logging in, it redirects to the login page, and when the user logs in, it lands them to the `my-account/` page.

I want to change the current scenario to make the user redirect to the referring page, where he came from. I tried the following things, which never worked.

#### Using a `HTTP_REFERRER`

In the `login/` form, I placed this bit of code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" />
```

#### Hacking `functions.php`

In the `functions.php`, I placed this bit of code:

```
if ( (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != 'logout') || (isset($_POST['login_location']) && !empty($_POST['login_location'])) ) {
        add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
        function my_login_redirect() {
                $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
                wp_safe_redirect($location);
                exit();
        }
}
```

**References:**

- [Redirect wordpress back to referring page after login](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/redirect-back-to-referring-page-after-login/)
- [WordPress Tip: Redirect to Previous Page After Login](https://longren.io/wordpress-tip-redirect-to-previous-page-after-login/)

---

I have also tried these and failed:

- [Redirecting users to referrer page after logging in using custom login form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/redirecting-users-to-referrer-page-after-logging-in-using-custom-login-form)
- [Redirect user to original url after login?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16004/redirect-user-to-original-url-after-login)

Nothing was working out. I am happy to provide further details if needed. Thanks in advance. `:)`

---

#### Update

I have modified the code this way:

```
<?php
    if(!is_user_logged_in())
        wp_redirect('/login/?redirect_to=' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
?>
```

This renders the login page this way:

```
/login.php?redirect_to=/my-account/subscription.php
```

This would be enough for me to authenticate and redirect. But I need to find the bit where the real redirection happens and I want to redirect it using the `redirect_to` parameter!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am having the same issue!

Comment: @ThomasNolan Actually I used a temporary variable! `;)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your setup, but here are few ideas:

### A) Display a login link with the `redirect_to` parameter set:

You could add the following to your custom template pages:

```
if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
{
    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', 
        wp_login_url( get_permalink() ),
        __( 'You need to login to view this page!' )
    );
}
```

This will generate a login link, for anonymous visitors, with the current page in the `redirect_to` GET parameter.

### B) Redirect to the `wp-login.php` with the `redirect_to` parameter set:

Notice that the call to `wp_redirect()` must happen before the HTTP headers are sent.

We can call it within the `template_redirect` hook:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 
    function()
    {
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() 
            && is_page( array( 'member-page-1', 'member-page-2' ) ) 
        )
        {
            wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) ); 
            exit();
        }
    }
);
```

where we restrict the access to pages with the slugs `member-page-1` and `member-page-2`.

### C) The native login form (in-line):

Another option would be to include the native login form, directly into the page content:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {

    if( ! is_user_logged_in() 
        && is_page( array( 'member-page-1', 'member-page-2' ) ) 
    )
        $content = wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => 0 ) );

    return $content;
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

where we restrict the access to pages with the slugs `member-page-1` and `member-page-2`.

*Notice you would have to take care of the archive/index/search pages.*

*Update:* I simplified it by using the [`wp_login_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url) function.

Comment: I already give the `redirect_to` to the `login.php`. Check the updated answer. But post logging in, it just goes to `my-account`, which has to be replaced with `redirect_to`.

Comment: Notice that you must use `wp_redirect` before the HTTP headers are sent. You might want to use the `template_redirect` action, for example.

Comment: Okay, where does the `redirect()` happen?

Comment: The `wp_redirect()` is pluggable but you can also access the `wp_redirect` filter.

Comment: I don't understand. Pluggable meaning?

Comment: You can override it with your own `wp_redirect()` function, but I don't recommend that.

Comment: Nice answer, but didn't manage to work on a custom login page!

Comment: If your custom `login.php` works with the `redirect_to` parameter, then I think you should be able to just replace `wp-login.php` with `login.php` in the above code snippet. PS: I'm assuming you're using WordPress pages and not bare PHP files.

Comment: Custom login only doesn't work. The original `wp-login.php` works with redirection.

Comment: This doesn't work, yet I am accepting the answer for your hard-work. I am continuing this in [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171650/wordpress-redirect-to-referring-page-after-logging-in). Can you come there?

Comment: ok thanks, it looks like you found a Javascript solution that works for you over there.

Comment: Yes buddy, it was my mistake. The bespoke code was a JavaScript one! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Usgin `get_permalink()`, as suggested in the accepted answer, will work only if you are in a post (of any type) but it won't work, for example, if you are in a category archive. To make it work anywhere, the current URL is needed, not matter what type of content we are seeing.

To get the current URL in WordPress we can get the current request from the global `$wp` object and append it to the site url using `add_query_arg()`. We can use the result in the `redirect_to` parameter of `wp_login_url()` function:

```
wp_login_url( site_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) ) );
```

The same approach can be used with `wp_logout_url()` if needed:

```
wp_logout_url( site_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) ) );
```

Comment: The project died an year ago. Well, what's the point of answering now? Coz did you even read the previous accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, I read the previous answer and I think I could give a better answer, maybe not for you but for others. Note that this site (and any of the StackExchange sites in general) is used as reference by thousands of people and they can get outdated answers; that is why giving new answers or updating old answers is always very wellcome. **Remember taht the help you get here is not only for you**.

Comment: Ha ha... Man, I hold 62k in StackOverflow. I understand what you mean. That's a custom code gone wrong, and I am not sure it will help? Will it? If so, Thank you so much.

Comment: I have no doubt that it can help. For example, [this other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/210374/how-to-place-login-logout-link-on-menu-that-redirects-users-back-to-current-page) has been marked a few minutes ago as duplicated of the one we are discussing.

Comment: Ha ha... Fine. I give up. You are right! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code in your custom login page

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:
   $args = array(
    'redirect' => esc_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), 
    'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
    'label_username' => __( 'Email' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
    'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
    'remember' => false
);
wp_login_form($args);
echo '<p><a href="' . wp_lostpassword_url($redirect) .'">Lost Password</a></p>';
}
```

This will redirect the user to referrer page, after login.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: This does answer the question. You can see that the user is redirected to custom login page `<?php
    if(!is_user_logged_in())
        wp_redirect('/login/');
?>`

Comment: Kindly I would like to check the question's solution in [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171650/wordpress-redirect-to-referring-page-after-logging-in)...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but I am posting the solution so that it can help someone in need at the moment.

This is what I am doing and it is working perfectly.

```
function redirect_user_tologin(){
  global $post;
  $post_slug = $post->post_name;

  if(!is_user_logged_in()){
      if($post_slug == 'my-account') { //can add multiple conditions

          //create dynamic redirect page link
          $redirect = urlencode(site_url().'/'.$post_slug);

          //redirection
          wp_safe_redirect(site_url().'/wp-login.php/?redirect_to=' .$redirect);
          exit;
       }
   }
}
add_action('wp', 'redirect_to_login');
```

#### Explanation

If user is not logged in than `wp_safe_redirect` will take user to login page.

In order to redirect user after login, we will pass page link as value in `redirect_to` parameter so that it will take user to that particular page.

Login page url: `site_url().'/wp-login.php/`

Redirect page link: `redirect_to=' .$redirect`

Comment: Thank you... 