# How to place login logout link on menu that redirects users back to current page?

Tags: php, menus, login

I am working on an area of my site for members. However, I need a link on my menu that when clicked it will take people to my login form then back to the page they were previously on. I need the same with log out.

Example:
Bob logs in on page A.
Bob has a successful login.
Bob is returned to page A.

Bob clicks the logout link on page A.
Bob is returned to page A after being logged out.

EDIT: The other question did not seem to have anyway to add a login logout link to the navigation menu. This is what I need acomplished.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to referring page after logging in](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169704/redirect-to-referring-page-after-logging-in)

Answer (score 1):

Use `wp_login_url()` function with `get_permalink()` as a parameter, if a user is not logged in. Something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Login">Login</a>
```

And `wp_logout_url` function with `get_permalink()` as a parameter, if a user is logged in.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">Logout</a>
```

**EDIT:** instead of using 2 different functions, you may use

```
<?php wp_loginout(get_permalink()); ?>
```

that displays a login link, or if a user is logged in, displays a logout link

Comment: not sure about the use of `get_permalink` here as you might need that login link on pages that don't have a permalink. `$_SERVER['RESQUEST_URI']` (+ the query string maybe) might be a more robust option.

Comment: Even if you are on a page, `get_permalink()` will return the URL of this page. Don't worry :)

Comment: login page itself, (which might be a not interesting case here) do not have a permalink, other pages might have content for which the scheme of posts and taxonomies do not apply at all. And then there are the parameters, are you sure you should ignore them? (guess it might be different for different sites)

Comment: Every page/post has a permalink. This function returns the URL of the SCREEN that you are currently viewing.

Comment: pages and posts are just the most used way to construct URLs, but not all sites use them for all of their URLs. Again the login page itself is a great example for that.

Comment: search results pages also do not have a permalink

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that fixed my problem:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2 ); 

function add_login_logout_link( $items, $args ) {
    $pageURL  = 'http://';
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    ob_start();
    wp_loginout( $pageURL );
    $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    return $items;
}
```