# Disable Page if user not logged in

Tags: content-restriction

I am using the zoom plugin for creating workshops, and I want to make the nonusers cant access the workshops pages until they log in.

the link for each workshop will be different ex (https://******.net/zoom-meetings/slug) the post_type=zoom-meetings

I want to redirect them to the login page, and after they log in, it takes them to the same page they were at before redirecting them, and the page will be visible. And I have a custom login in page that I want to be used for logging in. (and the login has shortcode I can use as well)

this is the plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/video-conferencing-with-zoom-api/

Comment: There are several answers available for questions similar to yours. Your use of a plugin could complicate things a little. But, you might be able to develop your solution from this:
[Redirect to referring page after logging in](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169704/redirect-to-referring-page-after-logging-in?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I tried that but not working I have provided the plugin link